# Problems with using System.Collections.Generic; or something else

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{      
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

     public Game1()
     {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
     }

     protected override void Initialize()
     {                
        base.Initialize();
     }

     bool hasJumped = true;            
     Vector2 velocity;
     Texture2D player;
     Texture2D ground1;
     List<Vector2> vectors = new List<Vector2>();
     List<int> list = new List<int>();
     List.add(1);
```

`List.add(1);` result in 2 errors `"Invalid Token '(' in class,struct,or interface member declaration"` and `"using the generetic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requiers 1type arguments"`

What is going on please tell me

Comment: Please spend some time on formatting your question properly next time

Comment: the problem is not about the capital L maybe i have pasted it wrong look when i type "vectors" with "v" the program does not show it as registered

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov The program has other syntax errors. You cannot trust the IDE feedback in the presence of syntax errors. You should fix all the errors people have listed, and in future perhaps supply a more complete sample of code. Best wishes. K

Answer (score 3):

The correct case is `list.Add(1)`

Comment: This is one problem, but not the only problem.

Comment: @Servy That's true, but it is the problem that the question was about.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `list.Add(1)` instead of `List.add(1)`. The name of the instance is `list` not `List`, and the name of the method is `Add` not `add`. Also you can't have a method call in the body of the class but in the body of the some method within the class.

You can't have this in the body of the class:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
```

But you can create a `List` in the body and have a method like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
public void AddOne()
{
     list.Add(1);
}
```

Or you can declare a `list` in the body and then instantiate it in the method and call `Add` like this:

```
List<int> list;
public void CreateListAndAddOne()
{
     list = new List<int>();
     list.Add(1);
}
```

Comment: the capital letter is not the problem maybe i have pasted it wrong in my case when i write "vector" it does not show "vectors" as a registered command it shows only Vector2 Vector3 and Vector4

Comment: I presume that it is because of the call `list.Add(1)` (as I stated numerous times in the answer, people will get bored), the code can't be compiled so the IDE is not offering you the autocomplete for the `vectors` field.

Comment: y but i cant see an aswer for my problem you just say "the code can't be compiled so the IDE is not offering you the autocomplete for the vectors field." so what am i supposed to do ? or it is unknown ?

Comment: i see now just couldnt understand why the synstaxis is so wierd in this case... ill use your public void AddOne() method thx

Comment: I have already told you. Move the `list.Add(1)` call in some method or remove it from your code, you can find the examples in the second part of my answer. You can use fields that you declare in your class only in methods (constructors, other methods, eventhandlers etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `List.add(1)` use `list.Add(1);`.

**EDIT:**

Another thing you can't use it in that way in your class, but you need to use it into a method, constructor or a property. However a solution could be:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){ 1 };
```

Comment: No, that won't fix it. `Add` is not a static member of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Add` is not a static method.. it's an instance method.

Renaming your variable will help ease the confusion (remember, C# is case-sensitive):

```
List<int> myIntegerList = new List<int>();
myIntegerList.Add(1);
```

Comment: i have this  List<Vector2> vectors = new List<Vector2>(); why when i write "vector" it shows "Vector2" "Vector3" "Vector4" but not "vectors" after it is  registered above ?